# How to call with passing parameter stored procedure functions in postgres sql

Tags: php, postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, function-call

I am struggling with ***how to call PostgreSQL stored procedure functions with passing parameter***.I don't know and i have mistaken with passing parameter call the function.Please advice me.

This is my php file ***calling.php***

```
      include('connection.php');
      echo  $hud='15';
      echo $phc='80001';

      echo $Firstdate='2015-08-01';
      echo $Seconddate='2015-10-01';
      echo $Todate='2015-10-31';
      $dvn_sql =<<<EOF
      select * from prisonparam($hud text
      ,$phc text
      ,$Firstdate Date
      ,$Seconddate Date
      ,$Todate Date);
      EOF;
   $dvn_ret = pg_query($db, $dvn_sql);
      while($row = pg_fetch_array($dvn_ret))
      {   
      echo $ben_st=trim($row['sc']);
      echo $round=trim($row['scupto']);
      }
```

And This is my stored procedure functions

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prisonparam(dvn_cd text
      ,phc_cd text
      ,Firstdate Date
      ,Seconddate Date
      ,Todate Date) 
      RETURNS table (round text,sc bigint,scupto bigint)
      AS $$

      WITH a
      AS (
      SELECT round AS round
      ,Sum(ben_sc) AS SC

FROM prison_issue
WHERE (
        DATE BETWEEN Firstdate
            AND Todate
        )
    AND dvn_cd = dvn_cd
    AND phc_cd = phc_cd

GROUP BY round ORDER BY round
)
,b
 AS (
SELECT round AS round_up
    ,Sum(ben_sc) AS SC_up


 FROM prison_issue
WHERE (
        DATE BETWEEN Seconddate
            AND Todate
        )
    AND dvn_cd = dvn_cd
    AND phc_cd = phc_cd
GROUP BY round ORDER BY round
)
  SELECT b.round_up AS round
 ,coalesce(a.sc, 0) AS SC
 ,coalesce(b.sc_up, 0) AS SCUPTO

 FROM a
 RIGHT JOIN b ON a.round = b.round_up

 $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

error is

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: 
ERROR: function prisonparam(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist 
LINE 1: select * from prisonparam(15,80001, 2015-08-01,2015-10... ^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 
in C:\wamp\www\mhp\test.php on line 12
```

Comment: Please add new information as edits to a question, not comments.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. There's no function `prisonparam` that takes 5 integer arguments. You might need to add type casts.

Comment: sir see calling.php. that is passing parameter problem

Comment: sir please tell me the passing parameter.it is the my final problem

Comment: Use `pg_query_params` not string formatting and `pg_query`. That will probably resolve your issue and fix the giant SQL injection hole in your code.

Comment: sir please refer any code

Comment: If you are still stuck after changing your `$dvn_sql =<<<EOF .... ` and `pg_query` to use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php), edit the question to show your new attempt and comment here then I might help out more. This isn't a code-writing service though, and *especially* for an assignment you should be trying to do this yourself, seeking help when totally stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing the query

```
select * from prisonparam($hud text
      ,$phc text
      ,$Firstdate Date
      ,$Seconddate Date
      ,$Todate Date);
```

with

```
select * from prisonparam('$hud','$phc','$Firstdate','$Seconddate' ,'$Todate');
```

or

```
$dvn_sql ="select * from prisonparam('".$hud."','".$phc."','".$Firstdate."','".$Seconddate."','".$Todate."')";
```